# React.js "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using React.js. Im getting error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in this place : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBS1d.png)

```
  17 |    };
  18 | 
  19 |    return (
> 20 |        <div>
  21 |            {items.map(item => (
  22 |                <h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>
  23 |            ))}
```

My code is:
  [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBS1d.png)

Anybody knows the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some basic problems:

1. You have to change the API URL. The one in your screenshot is a dead URL.
2. You have to change the property name you are trying to access. It is `jsonItems.data`, not `jsonItems.items`.

For taste, you have declared `items` twice using the `const` keyword. I suggest renaming `items` in the scope of your `fetchItems` function. For example:

```
const fetchItems = async() => {
  const data = await fetch("https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/store/get");
  const jsonItems = await data.json();
  console.log(jsonItems.data);
  setItems(jsonItems.data);
};
```

For it to work as you want, you will have to change your render method too:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {items.map(item => (
          <h1 key={item.itemId}>{item.item.name}</h1>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
```

here is the final thing for you to copy-paste:
https://gist.github.com/peaceful-james/db0805edba1bad5323f66701ee5d0e4e

Comment: It works. But the page is empty. How can I get the data from page?

Comment: If my answer solved the original problem of `"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"`, please give me a vote :) I will keep helping you.

Comment: It does, but just partly :D

Comment: OK. I get `access denied` when I try to fetch from that API.
Can you please post the raw json you get when you hit that link?
https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get
Then I can tell you how to parse it.

Comment: I'm getting the same.

Comment: OK so you are getting empty data from the API. There is nothing to display.
However, I believe I have solved the original problem and helped fix a mistake in your code with the duplicate `const` declaration.

Comment: Your approach is approximately correct. If there was data, it might work. The only real problem is the redeclaration of a `const`.
FWIW I think this "fortnite api" is no longer maintained (i.e. it is dead). You might want to find a different API to explore.

Comment: Ok, plus for you:) I'am still looking for a solution for someone to help :)

Comment: Try using this URL instead: https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/store/get

Comment: Still getting this: https://prnt.sc/sz2mh9

Comment: OK i have got it working now. I will make a gist with the working code.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Waiting for an answer!:)

Comment: @RokasAšmena I have made a working example for you:
https://gist.github.com/peaceful-james/db0805edba1bad5323f66701ee5d0e4e

:)
good luck with the rest

Comment: It works, you are the best!

Comment: No problem, fellow coder! Now accept my answer so I can start getting some reputation :D

Comment: I'm new here. I have did everything right? everyone is happy? :D

Comment: I am very happy :) You are good.

Answer (score 0):

`items` is not defined at some point when you're rendering this component. One way to guard against this happening is to use a *short circuit* evaluation:

```
{items && items.map(item => (
  <h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>
))}
```

Taking a look at your code, `items` is undefined until your data fetch completes, so this guard should work. Another option that many folks use is to have  some kind of "Loading" display while the fetch is happening. This can be accomplished using a *ternary operator* as follows:

```
{!items ? "Loading..." : items.map(item => (
  <h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>
))}
```

Comment: It works, error doesn't come up, but it doesn't show the data I want. I want to show items from page "https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get".

Comment: The issue is likely that the data is not returned how you're expecting it from the API. Try adding a `console.log` statement to your function to see what `items` is.

Answer (score 0):

`items` gets set when the async function completes.
But before that render is called.
you can use the below code to solve this issue.

```
{items && items.length > 0 && items.map(item => (<h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>))}`
```

Comment: The error message shows that `items` is `undefined`, hence `items.length` would *also* throw an error.

Comment: use the edited answer

Comment: Good! but it's empty blank. How should I get data that I want?

Comment: Can you comment what data you are getting in the console.log you have in the async function

Comment: In app, console is showing that there is no data, but I'm doing everything exactly from the tutorials :/

Comment: It means the data is not there. 
Check in the XHR tab, what response you are getting or console the response itself.
It must be showing 'Access denied' error

Comment: Sorry for dump question, but what is XHR tab?

Comment: Refer https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Answer (score 0):

Just modified like the following way:-

```
 {items && items.map(item => (
        <h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>
))}
```

Comment: Now it shows blank page. I need items data inside :(

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your initial state was an empty array. It should not show the error on on initial render. But when you set items, it becomes undefined. Can you share the data you are getting from the fetch request..

Instead of async/ await you can also try it this way

```
fetch('fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => setItems(data.items));
```

Comment: What do you mean by data from the fetch request? You want to know what data should I get?

Comment: Yes, what data are you getting from the request you made to 'fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get'  ? my guess is that when you do items.items it gives you undefined..

Comment: I'm not getting anything. But I should get: Gemini, Cryo Hops, Plasma Carrot, Daring Duelist and etc...

Comment: Can you try doing console.log(data) after this line `const data = await fetch('fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get')`.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sz2th7

Answer (score -1):

As Nick explained, `items` not defined when initial render happens. We can do

```
{items.length && items.map(item => (
  <h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>
))}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: if `items` is not defined, why would `items.length` not throw an error?

Comment: My bad. I saw that the items are initialized to empty array and so this condition check would suffice. Looks like the fetch call is setting the local state item to undefined. As explained above, setting the local state from `items.data` would resolve. Also try adding `try-catch` block that would catch error.